# How to force "Switch to SoundCloud Classic"

Tags: soundcloud

SoundCloud has an option within it's "More..." drop down menu to switch back to classic layout.

How to always force SoundCloud Classic layout to begin with?

if it were a greasemonkey script:

@include *soundcloud.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This two line of JavaScript will do it.

**updated code**

```
   var menuDropD = document.querySelector(".header__moreButton").click();
   document.querySelector(".moreMenu__classic").click();
```

This code will trigger a click on the dropdown menu and then the link that will take you to the old Layout.

To add the script in Greasemonkey, click on the dropdown next to Greasemonkey icon in Firefox and press "New User Script.."

[image: Add a new script to Greasemonkey manually]

Fill up the details :

[image]

Now click "OK", a new window may open, paste the script below the last line and Save

[image]

The script has been added. Go to the soundcloud homepage and you will be redirected to the old layout in seconds.

Comment: Ok so thats the code. How would I then be able to use it? I tried creating a .js file with the greasemonkey specifics before it to include the address to activate code but it's not working.

Comment: @user176540 Updated the answer.